# How to get Org-mode Babel src code block language value?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I set org-mode Babel to open rhtml block with web-mode.

```el
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("rhtml" . web))
```

And I have configure company-robe for completing for Rails code in `erb` engine.

```el
(defadvice company-robe (before web-mode-set-up-ac-sources activate)
    "Set `robe-mode' based on current language before running `company-robe'."
    (if (equal major-mode 'web-mode)
        (let ((web-mode-cur-language (web-mode-language-at-pos)))
          (if (string= web-mode-cur-language "erb")
              (unless robe-mode (robe-mode))
            (if robe-mode (robe-mode -1))
            ))))
```

The upper advice work correctly in normal file `index.html.erb` file.

But web-mode can't recognize engine correctly in Org-mode babel block.
When I run `(web-mode-language-at-pos)`, it shows `html`.

The author of web-mode suggest me to use `web-mode-set-engine`.

```el
(web-mode-set-engine "erb")
```

Here the original question I asked in web-mode issues: https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/678

My problem is the org edited src buffer's major-mode is `web-mode`, but I want to set `web-mode-engine` to `erb`. The only identity in src block is this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC rhtml

#+END_SRC
```

I checked out Org-mode source code, found some functions relative with this.

- `org-src-construct-edit-buffer-name (org-buffer-name lang)`
- `org-babel-expand-src-block`

  - `org-babel-get-src-block-info` (it should return a list: (language body header-arguments-alist switches name indent block-head) )

I tried to run `(nth 0 (org-babel-get-src-block-info))` in opened src buffer which is opened by `[C-c ']`.
But only get `nil`.

Comment: `org-babel-get-src-block-info` will return information when run in the org buffer with point within the src block. The command `org-babel-view-src-block-info` also is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, add an advice to get lang before `[C-c ']` keybinding.

```
;; let Org-mode Babel src code block auto set `web-mode-engine' for rhtml.
  (defadvice org-edit-special (before org-edit-src-code activate)
    (let ((lang (nth 0 (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))
      (if (string= lang "rhtml")
          (web-mode-set-engine "erb"))
      ))
```