# How to find the org babel src code block type

Tags: org-babel

When point is inside an org src code block, how can I determine the code type/mode of that block? org-babel does mode specific syntax highlighting for emacs-lisp but I can't quite grep how to know I'm inside an emacs-lisp block for,eg, language specific help lookup.

Comment: There are many questions that are more-or-less duplicates of this one, so it's probably a good idea to search for `org-babel-get-src-block-info`, select the best one (if there is no exact duplicate) and mark this one as a duplicate of it. That way, related questions are grouped together and we avoid balkanization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Org-mode Babel src code block language value?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20395/how-to-get-org-mode-babel-src-code-block-language-value)

Answer (score 0):

from #emacs IRC :

```
(car (org-babel-get-src-block-info))
```